# Reset state when modify ng-repeat by orderBy and/or filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am very new with Angular JS, but I can understand JS in general. Angular have a completely different approach so I can't figure out how to do this:

Got an array of objects so I can sort by a property and filtering by a string provided by the model attached to the input "query".

Everything works fine until I need to preserve the objects grouped by the property  "`group`", when the array is filtered by a keyword typed in the input.

```
<input ng-model='query' type='text'>    
<div ng-repeat='reservation in reservations | filter: query | orderBy: "group"'>
  <span as-reset-list='{{$last}}'></span>
  <h2 ng-show='CreateHeader(reservation.group)'>Group</h2>
  <div>Group:  {{ reservation.group }} - ID: {{ reservation.id }}</div>
</div>
```

To print a header indicating the group I'm using a variable "`currentGroup`" defined in the `$scope` so I can compare to the current object.group in the loop.

```
function RestaurantCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.restaurants = [/* data */];
  $scope.currentGroup = '';

  $scope.CreateHeader = function(group){
    showHeader = (group!=$scope.currentGroup);
    $scope.currentGroup = group;
    return showHeader;
  }
}
```

BUT when a search who doesn't have results is made and repeat another search, the variable loses the value or something so the grouping not works as is expected.

How I can achieve this? I've tried creating a directive so I can reset the value of the variable "currentGroup" but it doesn't work always.

A working example of my code is here http://jsfiddle.net/5HZYt/

Comment: what do you mean by *" the sorting not works as is expected"*? please be specific. it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In effect, the sorting is working but the grouping doesn't.  When the app starts, is correctly sorted by group, but when a search is made the grouping breaks. I think is for the $scope.currentGroup variable but I can't figure out how to reset that variable in the filter event. Here's a gif that shows what I'm talking about http://cl.ly/image/2F3C3f2Z0e0S

Comment: @asumaran I saw the approach. I recommend you to pre-group your data. That solution looks funky.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably with your ng-model setting. It looks like you are setting ng-model to a simple scope variable and when that changes the ng-model loses the binding. TO avoid this, try setting ng-model to the property of an object so that when the value changes, angular retains the reference to the object.

something like this:

```
$scope.modelObj = {prop:"This Value"};
```

Then..

```
<input ng-model='modelObj.prop' type='text'>
```